# public function in Excel that does not work properly as UDF

Tags: excel, mouseover, udf, vba

I've use [this](https://superuser.com/questions/802479/how-can-i-trigger-an-excel-macro-by-hovering-a-mouse-over-a-cell) hack to intercept a mouse movement on a cell.
In A1 I have imputed the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(HYPERLINK(OnMouseOver(ROW(),COLUMN()),"Click here"), "Click here")
```

Then I've written the following function to clear all the borders in a large range and draw thick borders around the cell the mouse is hovering.

```
Public Function OnMouseOver(row, col)
Dim ra As Range
    Set ra = Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("A:BJ") 'Range("griglia")
    ra.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    ra.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    ra.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
    ra.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
    ra.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
    ra.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
    ra.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    ra.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone

    Set ra = ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col)
    ra.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    ra.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With ra.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Color = -16776961
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThick
    End With
    With ra.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Color = -16776961
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThick
    End With
    With ra.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Color = -16776961
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThick
    End With
    With ra.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Color = -16776961
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThick
    End With
End Function
```

This function does not clear existing borders and furthermore it draws only thin borders around A1. On the other hand it works as expected when I run it through this code:

```
Sub testfunction()
Call OnMouseOver(1, 1)
End Sub
```

Why this strange behaviour?

Comment: Even if you *could* alter the cell formatting with a UDF, you aren't actually ***returning*** anything, so your first argument to `HYPERLINK` is `Empty`.

Comment: @Comintern - check the link at the top of the question

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me - I could set the color but not the linestyle to xlNone

```
Public Function OnMouseOver(row, col)
     With ActiveSheet
        .Range("C5:H23").Borders.Color = RGB(200, 200, 200)
        .Cells(row, col).Borders.Color = vbRed
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: You can set the color but not the linestyle. And I imagine also the width. So, it does NOT work also for you.

Comment: Sorry, I intend weight, not width.